# Как убрать 'T00:00:00' в DATE в js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

Вывожу таблицу в react.js через rest.api(C#) из MySql

Дата выводиться таким образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Так вот вопрос, как убрать при выводе ту часть которая идёт после основной даты? Тобишь "T:00:00:00" (в MySql стоит DATE на столбце, а не DATETIME)

Код для вывода:
До render

```
this.state={
        projects:[],
        modalTitle:"",
        nameProject:"",
        startDate:"",
        stateProject:"",
        description:"",
        idProject:0
    }
}

fetch(variables.API_URL+'Project')
        .then(response =>response.json())
        .then(data=>{
            this.setState({projects:data});
        });
```

После

```
<tbody>
                {projects.map(dep=>
                    <tr key={dep.idProject}>
                        <td>{dep.idProject}</td>
                        <td>{dep.nameProject}</td>
                        <td>{dep.startDate}</td>
                        <td>{dep.stateProject}</td>
                        <td>{dep.description}</td>
                        <td>
```

Comment: Вы выводите из бд? Если да, то вроде как можно изменить формат записи того же времени в бд, или выводить уже средствами js в нужном вам формате - что-то типа formatDate(d), где d - ваша дата

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato Спасибо большое, по наводке нашёл как при SELECT изменить формат даты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если придётся убирать эту часть JS-ом, то можно воспользоваться методом [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
const date = new Date().toISOString();

console.log(date);
console.log(date.split('T')[0]);
```

Comment: отмечу ответом так как изначально задавал вопрос про то как сделать это на js

Comment: @jolychik Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

@tomato-magnet-regulato
Подсказал и я нашёл как при SELECT переводить дату в нужный формат

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d.%m.%Y') as new_date FROM 'your table';
```